# How to select an item in a listbox programatically using its index using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox which can be edited. Once an item in that listbox is edited and saved, the newly edited item is displayed in the list however its position changes. I want to be able to have that item selected or highlighted even afer its position changes. I can get its new index however I couldnt manage to find a way to have re-selected programitcally after its psoiton changes in the listbox!

Any help here would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to select the item by setting the properties `ListBox.SelectedItem` or `ListBox.SelectedIndex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListBox.SelectedIndex = newPosition;
```

or

```
ListBox.SelectedIndices.Add(newPosition);
```

with an optional SelectedIndices.Clear() before if you want just your item to be selected.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I dont know why I forgot about that! I'm still new to all this stuff!

Comment: `SelectedIndices` doesn't exist on WPF `ListBox`es.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that the itemssource is some kind of collection. why you dont use the SelectedItem property with Mode=TwoWay to select the item you want from your c# code?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourItemsCollection}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

another way is to use the [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) MoveCurrentTo method. all you have to do is to create a ICollectionView with [CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx)(this.YourItemsCollection). if you take this way you do not need binding to SelectedItem but you have to set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true for your listbox.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just followed Vladimir's suggestions and things work :)

Comment: np:) since mvvm and wpf binding i did not use the index stuff anymore ;)